# MacOS Catalina переменные окружения

Tags: macos, mac, path

Подскажите как устанавливать переменные окружения на маке. В гугле все довольно просто и привычно:

```bsh
export GOPATH=$HOME/Documents/work/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

если нужно каждый раз назначать их при запуске системы -- редактируем `.bash_profile`.

---

Все бы хорошо, только данные переменные работают строго внутри сессии терминала, перезапустил терминал и все. Вне терминала естественно нет их.

```bsh
sergey@iMac-Sergey ~ % export A=1
sergey@iMac-Sergey ~ % echo $A
1
```

В этот момент запускаю еще одно окно терминала:

```bsh
Last login: Sun Nov  8 03:54:42 on ttys000
sergey@iMac-Sergey ~ % echo $A
```

---

```bsh
sergey@iMac-Sergey ~ % cat ~/.bash_profile 
export GOPATH=$HOME/Documents/work/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
sergey@iMac-Sergey ~ % echo $GOPATH

sergey@iMac-Sergey ~ %
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас SHELL не `bash`, а `zsh`, соответственно и файл c настройками `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: Благодарю, помогло!